# Minimize boot time on headless ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ubuntu-12.04, init, headless

I am trying to remove as much processes as possible to minimize the boot time on a  beaglebone running ubuntu minimal.
So i want to remove udev-fallback-graphics and all plymouth processes.
I tried 'sysv-rc-conf' and 'rcconf' and  'update-rc.d -f' and nothing worked.
By removing those processes i can gain about 4-5 seconds which is very important for the project i have.
The dmesg gave me this:

```
[    7.855712] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   10.704010] init: udev-fallback-graphics main process (443) terminated with status 1
[   10.853881] PHY: 0:00 - Link is Up - 100/Full
[   10.854125] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   11.418457] init: plymouth main process (174) killed by ABRT signal
[   11.446380] init: plymouth-splash main process (470) terminated with status 2
[   13.843292] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (686) terminated with status 1
```

Comment: `upstart` is supposed to paralellize bootup as much as possible, so deleting something that takes 5 seconds won't win you 5 seconds.

Comment: I disabled ipv6 and it saved me 20 seconds of boot time.The goal is to reach the boot time to about 5 to 6 seconds which is required by my project.Even if it's not 5 seconds Its good enough since its nearer to the goal

Answer (score 2):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/whats-the-recommended-way-to-enable-disable-services

upstart services aren't affected by any sysvinit config tool.  Apparently, to disable SERVICE, you need to create a file /etc/init/SERVICE.override containing the word "manual".

Comment: I have tried the sudo sh -c "echo 'manual' > /etc/init/SERVICE.override" command but cant figure out if it was any good because i must have stopped services necessary for network.So i cant tell if this is the answer.Tomorrow with further tests...