# Speeding up Virtualbox boot time

Tags: boot, virtualbox, performance, operating-systems

I am looking for tips and tricks to speed up the boot time of VirtualBox VMs. By "boot time", I mean the elapsed time between starting the VM and having a login window/prompt, so it covers VirtualBox internal stuff, bootloading process and OS startup.

The background is that I am setting up a Vagrant-based infrastructure for testing. It will be spinning up VMs by the dozens, that is why I would like to make this boot cost as low as possible. The current focus is Linux (Debian) but I'm also interested in suggestions for Windows and MacOS. I have full control over the Vagrant base box used and the VirtualBox settings.

I'm interested in both BIOS and EFI. I'd be happy to hear about package suggestion as well (for memory footprint reasons, I have `dropbear` and `udhcpc` instead of more standard `openssh-server` and `isc-dhcp-client`, but they could be poor choices performance-wise).

Related question: [Minimize boot time on headless ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/553439/minimize-boot-time-on-headless-ubuntu)

Some figures:

- currently, it takes my quite minimal Debian VM 8 seconds to reach a login console
- `dmesg` tells me that the network is ready after 4 seconds (which matters for `vagrant ssh`), I'll guesstimate 2 more seconds to actually get the prompt, so that leaves 2 seconds for the VirtualBox boot choice menu and bootloader (GRUB) process

Examples of tricks I am already using:

- I started with EFI but reverted to BIOS as I couldn't find a way to take control over the boot menu display time in EFI (see my comment [in this other question](https://superuser.com/a/1205411/338183))
- `vboxmanage modifyvm vagrant_base --bioslogodisplaytime 1` saves several seconds by setting the BIOS menu display time to 1 millisecond (`0` would set it to the default value, which is something like 3 seconds)
- `vboxmanage storagectl vagrant_base --name "Floppy Controller" --add floppy` saves 3 seconds (!) by avoiding a kernel timeout while looking for a floppy controller ("floppy0: no floppy controllers found") (blacklisting the `floppy` module is likely an alternative)
- set `--portcount 1` for the hard drive controller to avoid having the kernel enumerate the default of 30
- disable IO-APIC if allocating only one CPU to the VM

I'm keeping DHCP for now, but might switch to static IP configuration as this is costly wrt to boot timings, though it will likely become a networking issue once several VMs are booted.

Current timings are of course highly dependent on the hardware I use, which is not the production environment yet. I am not stress-testing the VM, so increasing the number of CPUs or using high speed storage (which is already an SSD) isn't what I want to look at for now.

Comment: I may not be understanding properly, but dozens of machines means have 64 GB of memory or more. And for me, even on a very fast SSD, starting two machines at the same time takes longer than starting one, then the other.

Comment: I'm not saying that there will be dozens of machines at the same time. However, throughout a test campaign, there will be dozens of VM launched and stopped. These are lightweight VMs, meant to be created and thrown away, the current setup has a low RAM setting (128MB) from VirtualBox. I essentially want to get rid of time lost in a 5 seconds VirtualBox boot menu countdown, then a 5 seconds GRUB menu countdown, etc... Because these 10 seconds are more time than the actual Linux boot time itself.

Comment: Have you considered running VMs off a RAM disk? That does require a lot of memory, but if you have that it can really speed things up (it will make SSD look slow).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I gave it a try by wrapping the first `vagrant up` between `vboxmanage setproperty machinefolder [/dev/shm/vagrant_test,default]` calls. I am only seeing a small change regarding boot time (these are hand measurement, I do my best to be accurate). However, it had a significative impact for the building of my base box, which is now ~9x faster. Thank you for that!